# How to check Timer job error on production server

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

I am new to sharepoint and want to ask a question. I have to deploy a custom timer job on production and if there will be an error on production then how to debug it. what are the different ways to capture that error.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not wrap your code in a try/catch block then exception message will be displayed on timer job history page. It will state that timer job execution failed and if you press on 'failed' link you will get afore mentioned message.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your ULS Logs(Default location[However it might be different in some server]C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS) in the server to find out the errors thrown by the timer job.